# Hosting a PyCharm project in Dropbox

Tags: pycharm, dropbox, jetbrains-ide

I've been working on a project with PyCharm on my desktop and laptop, and for simplicity I keep the project folder in Dropbox.  However, PyCharm throws an error whenever I open the project on either device:

> Unable to save settings
>
> Failed to save settings. Please restart PyCharm

I don't have PyCharm open at the same time on the two devices, so I'm not sure why it's unable to save the settings in the .idea folder.

Has anyone been able to use Dropbox and PyCharm (or a JetBrains product) successfully?

NB: The reason I use Dropbox here despite managing the project with git via GitHub, is that it lets me work on a something and then switch computers without having to actually commit the code before it's done.  I'll often close out my laptop, leave the office, and then pick-up what I was working on at home on the desktop, before being ready to commit a chunk of code.

Here's a link to the idea.log file with the save errors in it, https://pastebin.com/jeUd6UDC

starts at the line marked:

```
2017-08-21 12:02:36,575 [  27776]   WARN - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - Save settings failed
```

Comment: That's not a very good reason. You can create branches and work in progress commits, then squash them to a single merge commit when you're ready, or if it's just you rewrite history on master.

Comment: I understand that, I'm talking more about leaving code in a very rough state on one computer and cleaning it up on another, i.e. stopping in the middle of writing a function declaration etc... Those are not points at which I necessarily want to commit, but it'd be useful to have those files synced across computers since it's a common workspace.

Comment: What kind of error it reports in `idea.log` (it may have some more details there). But in general -- you may configure / setup your project in such way that it will keep `.idea` subfolder (project settings) outside of the Dropbox synced folder so only actual code gets synced -- that might be enough.

Comment: I've added a log file.

Comment: I've submitted this as a bug to JetBrains, the report can be found here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25741